# Bounded from below implies the existence of infimum?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

There exists proposition that says that every sequence bounded from above admits a supremum.

Is it also correct to say that every sequence bounded from below admits an infimum?

Tks

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Yes: if $(a_n)$ is bounded below, $(-a_n)$ is bounded from above, hence has a least upperbound $M$ and it's easy to check $-M$ is the greatest lower bound of $(a_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if bounded from below then the infimum exists, if the least element is in the set then it can also be called minimum of the set.